# What should I look for in electronic measurement of body composition?

Tags: body-measurements, measurements

Would one combined with a scale be sufficient?  Or is better to measure on other points?

Is the accuracy about the same for all scales?

One thing I really need is something that stores or transmits the information, so i don't have to note it down everything.

Comment: The storing/transmitting thing is gonna be VERY hard - I cant say I know of anything that would do that. Is writing 2 numbers down such a big effort?

Comment: The tiny Fitbit does that (And they also have this kind of balance)

Comment: I have a withings scale. I'm not certain how accurate it is (no handheld sensor) but I used it for tracking a trend over time. It sets up on your wifi and links automatically with their website. http://www.withings.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use a body composition monitor, look for one that includes the upper and lower body.  If you get one combined with a scale that you step on, get one that includes the hand held sensor so that your upper body is included in the measurement.

Accuracy depends.  A monitor can over-estimate or under-estimate, but if you are using it to track your progress, ie are you improving over time, then they can be a useful tracking device.

Units do have memory for different periods of time such as up to 90 days.

For more information on measuring body composition, you will find a lot of helpful information here:   [How can I calculate my body fat percentage?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/262/how-to-calculate-body-fat)

Comment: I think handheld sensors might not be accepted in the bathroom :-)

Comment: So i might buy a separate instrument later.

Comment: About accuracy- the important thing is to measure small changes in short times. But my assertion is that for instruments measuring the same way it is probably not a big difference