# How to calculate body fat using calipers?

Tags: body-fat, body-measurements

One of the trainers in my local gym did my measurements with a fat caliper. He unfortunately has not had time to calculate the fat percentage.

I have the numbers and figured might as well do it myself but I not sure what formula to use. I can't match up all the body parts since he uses some different names.

He used the caliper in 6 areas:

- bicep
- tricep
- scapula
- Illioc
- calf
- Lower Back

What formula can I use that I can plugin my numbers to calculate my body fat percentage?

Comment: There are a number of online calculator you could use: - [Linear software has 6 different body fat calculators](http://www.linear-software.com/online.html) - [free online body fat calculator](http://www.free-online-calculator-use.com/skin-fold-test.html) You can read this [nerd fitness article](http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2012/07/02/body-fat-percentage/) for background information regarding body fat percentage, what it means, looks like and how to measure it.

Comment: That first link is money from an Exercise Scientist's point of view. If you have the data for the 7-fold Jackson/Pollock, that would be best. You have enough data for the Durmin/Womersley test though (I don't know a lot about this one).

Answer (score 1):

You can put those numbers into a site like: http://www.linear-software.com/online.html

And you should get a good BF% number back.

Not sure what Illioc is though?

Comment: It probably refers to the Illium, which is part of the hip bone (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip_bone)

Comment: Indeed, looks like they mean the Iliac crest, which the website refers to as the Suprailiac

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous free [app's](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.arcalot.biometrics) around that will estimate and track body fat from a set of Skinfold measurements (an give you the formula), but if you want do do it the hard way there are hundreds of academic papers in existence that propose and/or test a multiplicity of different regression equations, for different populations eg. [Validation of anthropometric equations for the estimation of body density in professional soccer players](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/rbme/v13n3/en_v13n3a05.pdf)

Based on your readings above I'd suggest:

```
Durnin and Rahman, 1967 (age: 18-34 R=0.83 ESE=0.0069):  
  fatPct =  495 / (1.161 – 0.0632 * Math.Log10(bicepSF + tricepSF + subscapularSF + supraIliacSF)) - 450
```

But there are numerous other formulas eg.

- [Alternative Skinfold Measurement Formulas to Calculate Percent Body Fat](http://www.umich.edu/~exphysio/mvs.240/AdditonalLabs/Pred.Bodyfat.Skinfold.6.3.pdf)
- [The Ideal Way to Measure Body Fat](http://www.accumeasurefitness.com/ideal-way-to-measure-body-fat-percentage.html)
- [NHANES (National Health and Nutrition Examination Survey) - Anthropometry Procedures Manual](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nhanes/nhanes_07_08/manual_an.pdf)
- [HOW TO MEASURE YOUR % BODYFAT AN INSTRUCTION MANUAL FOR MEASURING % BODY FAT USING SKINFOLD CALIPERS by Wallace C. Donoghue](http://www.harpendenservicecenter.com/How%20to%20Measure%20book%202009.pdf)
- [Lange Skinfold Caliper](http://www.langeservicecenter.com/lange%20manual.pdf)
- [Syndex System 1 Skinfold Caliper](http://www.skyndex.com/resources/SKYNDEX%20SYSTEM%201%20Manual.pdf)
- [How to use the Expert Skinfold Caliper](http://www.amstelmedical.nl/pdf/130311032942_howtousetheexpertfatmeasureincl.nl.pdf)

[image]

Comment: related: [How to calculate Body Fat %](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/262/how-to-calculate-body-fat?lq=1)