# How much fat I can safely lose?

Tags: weight-loss

I'm 25 years old (soon will be 26), height 174cm and weight is 77KGs. After reading some questions here I realized that in order to achieve my dream body shape ([link](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/17932/achieving-the-perfect-body-shape)) I need to lose as much fat as I can. My questions are:

1- How much fat I should lose?

2- It seems there is a difference between fat and weight, so how can I measure how much fat I have now?!

Comment: Have you checked this q/a about [body fat measurements](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/262/how-to-calculate-body-fat/2592#2592)?

Comment: Also, here is a [chart](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Body-Fat-Percentage-Chart.html#Men) for healthy levels of body fat.

Answer (score 0):

A weight loss of one pound a week is safe. It is safe in terms of nutrition and you without yoyoing back to your original weight. You could go beyond that but be careful of being not able to keep up with your diet and going back to your previous weight, this is yoyoing back to your previous weight. I've seen this with people, get near their wanted body to fit into a dress or a bikini and after that, get fat once again. It's supposed to be a change in your lifestyle not just a diet which you go on and go off.

1. One pound of weight loss a week is safe.
2. Try to get a fat caliper to measure your body fat percentage and multiply it by your bodyweight to get how much your fat weigh. Body fat percentage is a much better information than Body Mass Index (BMI) which just uses your weight-height ratio.

Comment: I like how you stress the lifestyle change as opposed to a quick fix. Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'safe', though? Are we talking muscle loss, metabolic damage, malnutrition?